# Will implicit conversions lose information?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

According to https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

> "The important thing to remember about promotions is that they are
>   always safe, and no data loss will result."

However https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-in-c/ states that:

> "It is possible for implicit conversions to lose information, signs
>   can be lost (when signed is implicitly converted to unsigned), and
>   overflow can occur (when long long is implicitly converted to float)."

I understand that implicit conversions are safe, but I don't see how  no data loss will result. Which is accurate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first article talks about **promotions**, which is a specific type of implicit conversion.  There are other types of conversions that are also implicit conversions but aren't promotions.  A promotion can't lose information as you are always going to a wider type, i.e. a type where all the values representable by the type being promoted are representable by the type being promoted to (`int -> long long`, for example).

Other implicit conversions include: going from signed to unsigned, narrowing conversions, floating point to integer conversions.  These conversion may lose information, unlike promotions.